# Wordpress Custom URL Page

Tags: wordpress, url

I would like to be able to make custom URLs for users. For example, `example.com/john`, or `example.com/jane`. These are not WordPress users or authors these are usernames that I am bringing in from external resources. I want all of these URLs to go to a single page where I can display info for that user. I don't want the URL to be anything like `example.com/user/john`, just `example.com/john`.

Recap: I am wanting to see if a username is registered in the dabase.
If there is a user in the db for example 'john' the url 'example.com/john' should be accessible but if 'john' is not a valid username in the db, go to the 404 page.

I've tried to implement this but don't understand how to make this work. I added the following in my functions.php file.

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $args = array(
    'public'  => true,
    'label'   => 'profile',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/' )
  );
  register_post_type( 'profile', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Comment: Have you thought of using custom post types for those pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom post (ex: my_users), then add a rewrite rule [@codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/' )
```

At the beginning, the url was `my_users/user_name`, with the rewrite rule, it will be `/user_name`.

Define a single tempalte in your theme, in my case `single-my_users.php`.

But you will not be able to create a page with the same slug.

I hope that help u.

Comment: I've tried implementing this rewrite but am not sure how to do so correctly. Could you possibly elaborate a little more?

Comment: Go to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example, here there is example of how to register a custom post type. (i hope u know how to developp theme or plugin). Change th rewrite line with my code before.

Comment: I don't know how to implement this correctly. I updated the description with the code that I have played with, but am not having in luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm well aware this thread is old as hell, but in the off chance some other poor soul is running into a similar issue that Travis Hoki described above, here's what Nozifel was referring to in context:

```
      <?php

/**
 * Registers the `fake_post_type` post type.
 */
function fake_post_type_init() {
    register_post_type( 'fake-post-type', array(
        'labels'                => array(
            'name'                  => __( 'Fake post types', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'singular_name'         => __( 'Fake post type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Fake post types', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'archives'              => __( 'Fake post type Archives', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'attributes'            => __( 'Fake post type Attributes', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into fake post type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this fake post type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'featured_image'        => _x( 'Featured Image', 'fake-post-type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set featured image', 'fake-post-type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove featured image', 'fake-post-type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as featured image', 'fake-post-type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter fake post types list', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Fake post types list navigation', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'items_list'            => __( 'Fake post types list', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Fake post type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Fake post type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Fake post type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Fake post type', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'view_items'            => __( 'View Fake post types', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search fake post types', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No fake post types found', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No fake post types found in trash', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Fake post type:', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
            'menu_name'             => __( 'Fake post types', 'YOUR-TEXTDOMAIN' ),
        ),
        'public'                => true,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'rewrite'               => [ 'slug' => '/' ], // <-- RIGHT HERE!
        'query_var'             => true,
        'menu_position'         => null,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-post',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'rest_base'             => 'fake-post-type',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'init', 'fake_post_type_init' );
```